# Converting date formatted with 'th' to datetime for date comparisons?

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-dateutil

I know this has been asked in some form or another, but I'm wondering how to convert a date such as:

```
Saturday, May 18th, 2019
```

to something like `2019-05-18` so that I can compare it to other dates.  I understand dateutil can do so but unfortunately I'm using Pycharm and it won't let me install that package without upgrading Python from 2.7 to 3.  Is there a way to do this simply in Python?

Comment: But python2.7 is end of life, why not switch to python 3

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` with `re` module as well:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Saturday, May 18th, 2019'
>>> datetime.strptime(re.sub('(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)', '\g<1>', s), '%A, %B %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 18, 0, 0)
>>>
```

And print it nicer:

```
>>> print(datetime.strptime(re.sub('(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)', '\g<1>', s), '%A, %B %d, %Y'))
2019-05-18 00:00:00
>>>
```

Comment: U9-Forward :  thanks - this works almost perfectly, except for one small problem.  Replacing "nd" is problematic, since "Sunday" becomes "Suay".  Is there a way to throw in an exception?

Comment: i.e. EXCEPT if string = "Sunday" or "Thursday" (both of these would see characters deleted w/ the code above)

Comment: Use `re.sub('(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)', '\g<1>', s)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[The regex solution is preferable in my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56204336/1170207), but this is a solution without using `re`, for people not familiar with regexps:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = 'Saturday, May 18th, 2019'
sl = s.split()
sl[2] = sl[2][:-3] # remove 'th,'
datetime.strptime(' '.join(sl), '%A, %B %d %Y')
```